# How to draw on a canvas in Metro using C# and XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml, draw

I am looking to allow my user to draw their signature in a canvas within a Windows 8 Metro application.

Does anyone know of any examples using C# and XAML?

Answer (score 6):

Try this method,

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/InkPen-sample-in-CSharp-189ce853

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.aspx) panel and track all the pointer events like [PointerPressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed.aspx)/Moved/Released/Entered/Exited. Make sure you track all pointers by ID (call e.GetCurrentPoint(myCanvas) to get pointer ID), since you may have more pointer devices than just the mouse. Then just add some shapes from the [Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.aspx) namespace like the [Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.line.aspx) to the Canvas and you have a drawing.
The problem you might encounter is if you want to save your image, since the WriteableBitmap.Render() method of the previous XAML-based UI frameworks is not available in WinRT. [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/), which recently got a [WinRT version](http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2012/05/one-bitmap-to-rule-them-all.html) might help you there.

Answer (score -4):

do this in the XAML code's grid:

```
<Canvas>
   <Rectangle Width="80"
              Height="80"
              Fill="Red"
              Canvas.Left="80"
              Canvas.Top="80" />
</Canvas>
```

then run your code and it will have a square 80x 80y.